# Django on Gunicorn/Nginx - Stripe Webhooks Always Getting 400

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Production Setup: Django v3.0.5 on Nginx / Gunicorn / Supervisor (i followed directions from [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html))

(I don't think this is any issue but i am using dj-stripe for django/stripe integration)

While on development (django's built-in HTTP server).. everything seems to work (i.e. stripe can send webhook events just fine)... however, on production, i get emails saying that Stripe can't reach my server.

When I run

```
curl -D - -d "user=user1&pass=abcd" -X POST https://my.server/stripe/webhook/
```

I get this response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.15.9 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 19:44:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Cookie
```

However, non-webhook (i.e. visiting the website via browser) seems to work normally.. just webhooks.

Any idea where this is going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your production server has something different from your development one. What is the exact error message that you see in your Stripe event logs for the failed delivery attempts/

Comment: @taintedzodiac It's the same. Either 4XX or 3XX.

Comment: nginx conf: https://pastebin.com/hKChEyLu

Comment: Run `curl` with `-i` option and show the output. You'd better include nginx config with your question than posting it on pastebin.

Comment: i gave up. Supervisor/GUnicorn is a major pain in the ass to debug. Switched to uwsgi

Answer (score 0):

Your request doesn't have the Stripe secret which is needed for authentication.